# PHPMailer stops the script after send();

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to implement PHPMailer in a form. Everything works well, doing tls to O365 etc. But I seem to get a fatal error in the send(); because the script stops and hangs there. The mail is sent and recieved perfectly fine but the script stops. Just commenting out that single line makes it all work.

I've turned on all debugging I can find and used try/catch etc as well. I get nothing .. not in the browser, not in the error logs. I've tried to turn on all startup errors etc in php.ini and still nothing.

I don't know how to troubleshoot this but it stops my entire project for the moment.

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               
    
    $mail->isSMTP();
                             
    $mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
    
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
       
    $mail->Username = "XXXXXXXXX";                 
    $mail->Password = "XXXXXXXXX";                           
    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                           
    
    $mail->Port = 587;  
    
    $mail->SMTPOptions = [
         'ssl' => [
         'verify_peer' => false,
         'verify_peer_name' => false,
         'allow_self_signed' => true
                ]
    ];

    $mail->From = "XXXXXXXXXX";
    $mail->FromName = "XXXXXXXXXXX";

    $mail->addAddress("XXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXX");

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->AllowEmpty = true;

    $mail->Subject = "XXXXXXXXX";
    $mail->Body = "XXXXXXXXX";
    $mail->AltBody = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";


    try {
    $mail->send();
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
```

Comment: Add `die();` after try catch.  Maybe will see something usefull

Comment: The best way to troubleshoot this is of course by [reading the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host). It's most likely that your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP and you're getting a network timeout (you may need to wait 10 mins to see that error, because that's what the SMTP spec requires). Also, why are you suppressing certificate verification to a service that will not be publishing bad certs?

Comment: @Synchro I doubt that it's a SMTP error since the email is sent and received just fine .. so apparently the network part is working. The cert suppressing part was needed since I got cert errors when connecting to O365 without it. But I've tried this conf with other mailservers without tls as well with same result.

Comment: The troubleshooting guide just goes through SMTP errors. This is more likely a php error more than a PHPMailer error I'm guessing?

Comment: @Ingus die(); didn't give me any errors either.

Comment: No, the guide covers networking, DNS, TLS, and plenty of things beyond SMTP. If you're not seeing output from `die` either, I suspect you may be using output buffering incorrectly somewhere. Disabling TLS verification is simply hiding a problem that you should fix. It's most likely caused by outdated CA certificates, also documented extensively in the guide.

Comment: If you say that email is sent then something after id kills it. . What happens after email is sent?

Comment: I'm facing exact the same problem. Did anybody find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

How I solved it:

It seems that just requireing the classes as said in the readme makes a fatal php error. (Cannot declare class PHPMailer). The mail is send nevertheless.

I downloaded the files with composer, included the given autoloader and use:

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

Not it works as expected